# CurrentDb.openrecordset no result found

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to have a text box show the value that is associated with a certain value. I have a table with 2 columns, [Error_Code] and [Type]. I want to have a combobox with Error_Codes (which works) and whenever a selection is made, the [Type] will appear in the textbox. For some reason, I have been testing this to a msgbox, will change later.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim ERtype As String

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Error_Table where [Code]='" & Me!cb_Error.Value & "'")

MsgBox "testing: " & rst!Type_

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

This seems to return run-time error 3265, item not found. I have looked this up and my table name and fields are correct. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Could use DLookup() domain aggregate instead of recordset. Or maybe just include table in form or report RecordSource. Or build a multi-column combobox on form.

Comment: VBA really should not be necessary just to display the Type value. And even if you do use it to populate an unbound textbox, the same value will show for all records so unless form is in Single View, the output will be unsatisfactory. If you want to save the Type (why?), build multi-column combobox then expression in VBA can reference column that holds the Type value.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- Which line gives the error? -- Is the field name really `Type_` with the underscore?

Comment: It is the line: MsgBox "testing: " & rst!Type

Comment: Also, it does not have the underscore, that was a typo, still no result.

Comment: I tried the following,     Dim ErrType As String
    ErrType = (DLookup("Type_Err", "Error_Table", "Code_Err= '" & Me.cb_Error & "'"))
    
    Me.txt_Type = ErrType

Comment: Still gives an error, invalid use of null

Comment: If you put a debugger on those lines do any of the values show as null?  Either `Me.cb_Error`  or  `ErrType`.  Is it possible there is no Type value for the code you are looking up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this, but I think it should be:

```
Me.cb_Error.Value
```

Not:

```
Me!cb_Error.Value
```

Use the dot operator, not the exclamation mark.